# How often does MySQL (5.1) update the execution plans / index information?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I'm having a query that runs slow in production (50-100 seconds).
It is basically a big select with 3 joins (4 tables in total).
The joins are only done on the primary keys (referenced by the foreign keys)

With the `ANALYZE` statement, run multiple times (on all or only a few of my join tables), i'm able to get a good execution plan, and get the query execution to about 0.1 seconds.

I'd like to know how much I can rely on this new execution plan remaining the same for my query.

By what factors could the choice of this execution plan be determined?
AFAIK, the execution plan is tied to the index information, at least when the `ANALYZE` statement is run.

Cuz my query ran slow for as much as people remember - will it also run well for an undetermined amount of time?

If more information is needed, i'm happy to provide.

*I do not want to edit my `SELECT` statement in any way. This is because it is automatically generated, and wouldn't do any good if it is altered.

**[EDIT]**
InnoDB

**[EDIT]**
Found a way to modify my SQL query, so i wouldn't have to jump through hoops like this.

Comment: Analyze will update the statistics for your table so now the optimizer can choose a better plan.Run it from time to time depending how many changes,adding data,deleting data,indices etc.,have you made to the table.

Comment: the thing is that running `ANALYZE` can result in a worse execution plan being chosen for my query. So basically it can mess things up.

Comment: Maybe try query hints,spoon feed it. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html

Comment: I could do that, but would have to use a mysql-proxy to intercept the query - if no other solution exists, i guess i'd use it like that.

Comment: `ANALYZE` can change the data enough so the query planner chooses worse plan, sure. However are you really sure you can be smarter than it is?

Comment: at this point i've found another solution - turns out my assumption that i can't change the SQL code was wrong. Thx for the input